# Feature Selection for Text Classification

Tags: python, tf-idf, text-classification

I am working on a text classification problem in which the 100 most frequent words are selected as features. I believe the results could be improved if I use a better feature selection method? Any ideas? Could TF-IDF work? If yes, then how?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about text classification, probably better suited for http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603882/feature-selection-and-reduction-for-text-classification?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

to improve the results you can use Feature selection

1) Information gain

2) Chi square

3) Mutual information

4) Term frequency

TF-IDF you can see this [link](http://www.tfidf.com/) it will help you